# SilverStripe ModelAdmin with single tab

Tags: php, silverstripe

How can you join two models under a single tab of a ModelAdmin?

**Example**

```
private static $managed_models = array (
    'ProductCategory',
    'Product'
);
```

This generates two tabs, but I wish to display as two gridfields both under tab *Main*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the getEditForm function and manipulate the fields with it. For example:

```
public function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null) {
    $form = parent::getEditForm($id, $fields);
    $fields = $form->Fields();
    /* change your fields in here

    $fields->push(GridField::create(...))

    */
    return $form;
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of this method, the tricky part is how to remove the automatically generated Tabs and restructure everything under one tab.